# Can we use multiple SQL queries in single DB::statement("Query 1; Query 2") in Laravel migration?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, migration

I am trying to execute Laravel migration. I have multiple SQL queries in single DB::statement(). Is it possible to execute multiple SQL queries separated by semicolon?

Comment: `DB::unprepared()` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you can

```
DB::table('name')->insert(['id'=>1, 'var1'=> 'N18.1', 'var2'=>'CKD'],
            ['id'=>2, 'var1'=> 'N181', 'var2'=>'CKD'],
         
    }
```

this is one of example

Answer (score 0):

You can use Database Transaction as it is explained in documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#database-transactions)

```
DB::transaction(function () {
    DB::update(// Your Query);
    DB::delete(// Your Query);
});
```